# How to prevent calling IndexOf from ListView on each value change of scroll?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an implementation of `IList` to visualize the content of a collection, this aim to avoid has whole data in memory, so I store each element in a SQLite file.

```
public class DataCollection : IList, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    int IList.IndexOf(object item)
    {
        if (item == null) return -1;
        return IndexOf(item as ElementData);
    }

    private int IndexOf(ElementData element)
    {
        try
        {
            if (element == null)
                return -1;

            if(!isFiltered)
                return element.Id - 1;

            //en esta funcion es donde se ejecuta el query
            return _elementsCache.FetchIndex(element.Id);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Seemingly everything is working fine, but when the collection is over 200k elements, it's begin to exhibit performance problems in the GUI Thread. I found that GUI is constantly requesting for `IndexOf` of at least 70 elements on each change of the scroll value.
I am not sure why it's requesting ~70 elements on every changes the value of the scroll, but it's doing it. 
The collection is updated in real time and we have a functionality to set maximum of the scroll value (auto-scroll), so, every time this functionality updates the scroll value, the grid starts to call `IndexOf`.

There are two collections, one with all data and the other with filtered data. The most obviuous problem it’s in filtered collection, because to get the “index of” an element it goes to SQLite and execute the following query:

```
SELECT [index] FROM ElementData WHERE ElementId=<elementid>
```

> This query takes an average of 1 ms, since `ElementId` is an index.

This is my XAML of `ListView`:

```
<ListView x:Name                                          ="FilteredElementsListView" 
          GridViewColumnHeader.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown ="GridViewColumnHeaderPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
          PreviewLostKeyboardFocus                        ="FilteredElementsListViewPreviewLostKeyboardFocus"                    
          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode                  ="Display" 
          TextOptions.TextHintingMode                     ="Animated"
          PreviewKeyDown                                  ="FilteredElementsListViewPreviewKeyDown" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan                                 ="3"
          Margin                                          ="0,0,0,-0.333"                      
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode            ="Recycling">
```

`Style` for both  `ListView`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
     <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
     <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
     <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#333333" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling" />
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
     <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
     <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
     .
     .
     .
</Style>
```

Any idea how I could avoid this constant call of 'IndexOf` in the value change of scroll?

Comment: 200.000 items... that's a lot.

Comment: 1ms to check the index of a 200K item list is actually fantastic performance.  The only way to improve it at this point is likely to use more RAM.

Comment: but... I have more than 200k items, there is not a limit, i have cases with even for 19 millions. The problem is not the 1ms, the problem is that the "IndexOf" is called ~70 times on each "new item"; some times, there are 200 new items per second.

Comment: Why is `IndexOf` called that often? Because, there are 70 Items in the view cache... So on each new item the cache has to be recalculated.. and to check, if an item has left the "cached area" the ListView needs to check it's position.In that case with `IndexOf`.

Comment: I do not have cases where the elements have left the "cache area", can I prevent it from being re-calculated?

Comment: Well, search the web for "ListView Paging" here is an example i just found via Google (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/535722/Listview-Paging-in-Csharp) but there are lots available.